# How to use Redisson's Local Map Cache with RxJava

Tags: rx-java, redisson

```kotlin
val redisson = Redisson.create(config)
val redissonRx = redisson.rxJava()
redisson.getLocalCachedMap<String, User>("users", LocalCachedMapOptions.defaults()) // works
redissonRx.getLocalCachedMap<String, User>("users", LocalCachedMapOptions.defaults()) // there is no such method
```

Why I can't use Local Cached Map with RxJava? I cannot find any information why this feature would be unavailable in RxJava Redisson API.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is currently **you can't**. It's not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

Redisson provides RxJava3 interface for RLocalCachedMap object since 3.18.0 version